# MySQL Delimiting Data to be loaded

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to load data into a table that I have already created. This is what it currently has:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
        id int CHECK(id>0),
        pic varchar(100),
        url varchar(100),
        name varchar(200),
        type varchar(10),
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The format of the data is like this:

```
{"id":195624,"pic":"d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/users/195624-medium_jpg?1405525524","url":"angel.co/startup-ucla-accelerator","name":"Startup UCLA Accelerator","type":"User"},{"id":621586,"pic":null,"url":"angel.co/terri-getzug","name":"Terri Getzug, MD Clinical Professor of Medicine, Division of Digestive Diseases, David Geffen School of Medicine at UCLAepartment of Medicine","type":"User"}
```

All the tuples are in one line, and each tuple is contained within {}.

How can I load data into my table while getting rid of the extra attribute names?

I have tried something similar to this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './users.del' INTO TABLE Users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED      BY '"' LINES STARTING BY '{' TERMINATED BY '},' (id, pic, url, name, type)

SET id = TRIM(LEADING '"id":'),

pic = TRIM(LEADING ',"pic":'),

url = TRIM(LEADING ',"url":'),

name = TRIM(LEADING ',"name":'),

type = TRIM(LEADING ',"type":');
```

Comment: That's JSON format. AFAIK, MySQL doesn't have built-in support for this. Write a program in PHP that uses `json_decode()` and inserts into the DB.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any way to do this in MySQL? I'm not familiar with JSON unfortunately

Comment: Parsing complicated strings in MySQL is **really** painful.

Comment: A couple of options: [MySQL JSON UDFs 0.3.2](http://labs.mysql.com/) and [extract_json_value](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/extract_json_value.html) from [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html).